# EGODatabase does not retain inserted record

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

I'm using EGODatabase to process my data. When I tried to insert data into the database which I created with Base and attached to the project, the data that was inserted programmatically will not show up when I restart my app.However the data inserted manually using Base will show up just fine.

Following is the code for inserting data into the database:

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"db"]; 
    db = [EGODatabase databaseWithPath:path]; 
    if ([db open]) { 
        NSLog(@"Database is opened successfully!"); 
    } else { 
        NSLog(@"Database is failed to open!"); 
    } 

    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[aFeed feedID], [aFeed title], nil]; 
    [db executeUpdate:@"Insert INTO Feed (FeedID, Title) VALUES (?, ?)" parameters:params];
    EGODatabaseResult *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM Feed"];
    for ( EGODatabaseRow * row in results) {
        NSLog(@"ID: %@      Title: %@", [row stringForColumn:@"FeedID"], [row stringForColumn:@"Title"]);
    }
```

I appreciate if anyone can share me a working sample code for EGODatabase. I'm using EGODatabase because I might have multi-threading code that write to the database. 
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the database file from your bundle to the user's Documents directory before making changes to it. The bundle resources are read-only, that's why you can't update your data.

Put this in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sqlite"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database" ofType:@"sqlite"] toPath:filePath error:&error];
}
[fileManager release];
```